# Redefining %in% for matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I love being able to operate across matrix elements in R with operators like `==` and `|`:

```
(m <- matrix(1:4, nrow=2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4

m == 2 | m == 3
#       [,1]  [,2]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE
```

Unfortunately, `%in%` doesn't have this same nice behavior, and returns a vector instead of a matrix:

```
m %in% c(2, 3)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Noting that `%in%` is defined as `function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L`, I figured I could redefine `match` to get my desired behavior:

```
match <- function(x, table, nomatch = NA_integer_, incomparables = NULL) {
  m <- base:::match(x, table, nomatch, incomparables)
  if (is.matrix(x)) matrix(m, nrow(x))
  else m
}
```

While this does work if I explicitly call `match`, I still don't get the desired result when running `m %in% c(2, 3)`:

```
match(m, c(2, 3), nomatch=0L) > 0L
#       [,1]  [,2]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE
m %in% c(2, 3)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Why isn't `%in%` now returning a matrix?

Comment: Some of the diagrams [here](http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/) are what I thought of when reading your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @joran for pointing me to [this excellent article](http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/), which clarified for me why `%in%` was not using my newly defined `match` function. Here's my understanding of what's going on:

The user-defined `match` function is stored in the global environment, while the original `match` function is still stored in `namespace:base`:

```
environment(match)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
environment(base::match)
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

Now, consider what happens when I call `m %in% c(2, 3)`:

1. This executes the `%in%` function, which is just defined as `function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L`.
2. The function needs to find the `match` function, so it first searches in its local environment that was created as part of the function call. `match` is not defined there.
3. The next place to look for `match` is the enclosing environment of the function. We can figure out what that is with:

```
environment(`%in%`)
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

4. Since the original version of `match` (not the user-defined version) is defined in `namespace:base`, this is the version of the function that is called.

To get my matrix version of `%in%` to work, the simplest approach is to follow the advice of @Molx and redefine `%in%` so it's stored in the global environment (note that there's still an identical version of the function in `namespace:base`):

```
`%in%` <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
environment(`%in%`)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Now `m %in% c(2, 3)` will search for the `match` function first in its local function environment and then in the enclosing environment (`R_GlobalEnv`), finding our user-defined version of the `match` function:

```
m %in% c(2, 3)
#       [,1]  [,2]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE
```

Another way we could have gotten `%in%` to use the user-defined `match` function would be to change the enclosing environment of `base::"%in%"` to the global environment:

```
rm(`%in%`)  # Remove user-defined %in%
environment(`%in%`) <- .GlobalEnv    # Can be reversed with environment(`%in%`) <- asNamespace("base")
m %in% c(2, 3)
#       [,1]  [,2]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE
```

As mentioned by the commenters on @Molx's answer, the most sensible thing to do is to avoid all this headache by naming my new function something else like `%inm%`.

Comment: Or play the long game and petition r-core to modify `%in%` to be `%in%.default`, allowing you to define your own `%in%.matrix`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why your attempt didn't work, but I imagine that `%in%` will use `base:::match` regardless of your redefined `match`. But why not redefine `%in%` itself?

```
`%in%` <- function(x, table) {
  m <- base::match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
  if (is.matrix(x)) matrix(m, nrow(x))
  else m
}

m <- matrix(1:4, nrow=2)

m %in% c(2, 3)

#       [,1]  [,2]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE
```

As suggested in the comments and usually in terms of good practices, it would be safer to use a different name, like `%inm%` or `%min%`.

Comment: redefining a base function could be confusing to other users or the creator at a later date

Comment: Yes, I believe that since `%in%` is part of the `base` namespace, it will look there first for `match` and hence will always find `base:::match`.

Comment: @rbatt I agree, but that's he was trying to do in first place. Maybe creating `%inm%` would be safer.

Comment: ...and as @rbatt alluded to, I would probably write a new infix, like `%min%` or something to avoid collisions.

Comment: @joran `%min%` may avoid collisions, but `%inm%` seems better for avoiding confusion.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely solves the immediate problem (and the comment about naming is appreciated), though I'm still perplexed about why it doesn't work after redefining `match`.